# Must read an XML file, how to prevent it being parsed twice with OnInitializedAsync?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am converting my website from PHP to C# Blazor and I got a peculiar use case: each time a user access the page, my PHP script loads an XML file, organizes the data into HTML, and serves it to the user.

When converting this to Blazor, I discovered that `OnInitializedAsync` (or `OnInitialized`) is called twice. My problem is that parsing the XML file can be quite long. To work around it, I tried to create a singleton service, but then when the file changes, the users won't see the new version until the server is reloaded.

My question is twofold:

- I read the documentation but, as a novice in Blazor, I have a hard time understanding why `OnInitializedAsync` is called twice. Do you have a simple way to explain it to me?
- Considering I can't change the fact that I need to load an XML file, what would be your best advice to prevent it from being read twice?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "when the file changes" ?  Whatever you do there shouldn't be different with a service. It helps to be very clear about such requirements.

Comment: With a singleton service that loads the file at creation, it will stay in memory. So if the XML file changes, the users won't be able to see the changes since the service won't reload the file. In PHP, the file is loaded each time a user request the page (bbut only once compared to Blazor)

Answer (score 1):

You are "facing this issue" because your app is pre-rendering, which is why the OnInitializedAsync method is called twice. Specifically it is due to this code in the _Host.cshtml file:

```
<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</app>
```

Set it like this:

```
<app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
</app>
```

However, you may execute your code, if this is not an issue, in the OnAfterRenderAsync method, when the method's firstRender parameter is true (only first time this method is executed), and your affairs won't be processed twice anymore.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you! I'll try both these solutions. Do you know _why_ the two renders are needed? What is the purpose of the pre-render?